# Detect input() event while running a program and fail the method call

Tags: python, automated-tests

**Background**

I have a task to run many python methods against test suites in a batch. I wrote a program to dynamically define the methods and corresponding test cases (using `exec(str)`), and run the test cases automatically.

**Issue**

The correct code should not contain the `input()` statement, which requires user input. However, there is incorrect code that may contain `input()` statements, which blocks the running and waiting for user input. How could I detect if an `input()` is called and my program hung there? Are there approaches to fail such a method call and continue the program?

**Summary**

- How could I detect if an `input()` is called and my program hung there?
- Are there approaches to fail such a method call and continue
  the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### How could I detect if an `input()` is called and my program hung there?

Let's suppose you have two methods - one correct and one incorrect:

```
class Foo:
    def correct(self, x):
        return x
        
    def incorrect(self):
        # You shouldn't use input!
        a = int(input())
        return 42 + a
```

You can use the [`unittest.mock` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). Create a function that detects if any call of `input` was used:

```
import unittest.mock

def check(f, *args, **kwargs):
    # Store the real `input` function in a variable
    real_input = __builtins__.input
    
    # Use `unittest.mock` to catch any calls to this variable
    __builtins__.input = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
    
    # Call the desired function with the provided arguments
    f(*args, **kwargs)
    
    # Check if the fake `input` function was called
    result = __builtins__.input.called
    
    # Restore the value of the `input` function
    __builtins__.input = real_input

    # Return if the fake `input` function was called
    return result
```

You can use it like this:

```
foo = Foo()
print(check(foo.correct, 42))    # Outputs False
print(check(foo.incorrect))      # Outputs True
```

##### Are there approaches to fail such a method call and continue the program?

Replace the `check` function with

```
def check(f, *args, **kwargs):
    # Use a custom error so that, if the original function throws an
    # error, it wouldn't be catch mistakenly inside the `check` function
    class _MyCustomError(BaseException):
        pass

    real_input = __builtins__.input
    
    __builtins__.input = unittest.mock.Mock(side_effect=_MyCustomError())
    
    try:
        f(*args, **kwargs)
    except _MyCustomError:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    finally:
        __builtins__.input = real_input
```

With this modification the usage would be:

```
foo = Foo()
print(check(foo.correct, 42))    # Outputs False
print(check(foo.incorrect))      # Outputs True and fail the function with _MyCustomError
```